# Netezza:how to find MIN and MAX for LATEST continuous period for the person

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have data as below. Need to find the minimum date for a person is active on for the latest continuous period

SCENARIO 1

```
NAME | STARTDATE        | END DATE
--------------------------------------
```

name | 01-JAN-2016         | 31-DEC-2017
name | 01-JAN-2017      | 31-OCT-2018
name | 01-JAN-2018      | 31-DEC-2019
name | 01-JAN-2019      | 31-DEC-2020

I need output as:

```
NAME | STARTDATE        | END DATE
--------------------------------------
MIKE | 01-01-2018       | 31-12-2020
```

Scenario 2:-

```
NAME | STARTDATE        | END DATE
--------------------------------------
```

name | 01-01-2016      | 31-DEC-2017
name | 01-01-2017       | 31-OCT-2018
name | 01-01-2018       | 31-DEC-2019
name | 01-01-2019       | 31-DEC-2020
I need output as:

```
NAME | STARTDATE        | END DATE
--------------------------------------
```

name | 01-01-2019        | 31-12-2020

So basically output is MIN and MAX for LATEST continuous period for the person.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think you can do this with the following logic:

```
select name, max(startdate), max_enddate
from (select t.*,
             lag(enddate) over (partition by name order by startdate) as prev_enddate,
             max(enddate) over (partition by name) as max_enddate
      from t
     ) t
where startdate <= prev_enddate + interval '1 day'
group by name, max_enddate;
```

The subquery simply gets the previous end date and the overrall end date.

The outer query does two things:

- Filters for when a new period of activity begins.
- Aggregates to take the latest date when it occurs.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7deb8f9bcbd340862783fa77f6e735ce) is a db<>fiddle

Comment: @SivabalanDivya . . . I fixed a typo and added a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-island problem. Here is one approach that uses `lag()` and a cumulative `sum()` to build the groups, and then filter on the first group per `name`:

```
select name, min(startdate) startdate, max(enddate) enddate
from (
    select t.*, 
        sum(case when startdate = lag_enddate + interval '1 day' or lag_enddate is null then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by name order by startdate) grp
    from (
        select t.*, 
            lag(enddate) over(partition by name order by startdate) lag_enddate
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
where grp = 0
group by name
```